# what is the equivalent of FrameTicks in ListPlot3D?

Tags: graphics3d

I want to put my own Ticks along  ListPlot3D  axes as I do with 2D  plots.

example : FrameTicks -> {{{{0.4, 0.4}, {0.8, 0.8}, {1.2, 1.2}}, 
   None}, {{{0., 0.}, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, {1.0, 1.0}}, None}}

How to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For `Graphics3D` objects there is no `FrameTicks` option. Instead, there is the option `Ticks`:

```
data = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {10, 4}];

ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> All, 
  Ticks -> {{{0.4, 0.4}, {0.8, 0.8}, {1.2, 1.2}}, 
      {{0., 0.},.25,.5,.75, {1.0, 1.0}},  Automatic}, 
  DataRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]